# Rails + Cucumber: How to wait for javascript to finish before moving on to next step?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that uses jQuery and ajax. One part of the form is dependent on the jquery to load certain inputs into the form, however, sometimes my tests fail because they are so fast that they don't wait for the javascript to finish. Is there a way to wrap the function to wait for the javascript response before continuing? Right now I just use `sleep 1`:

```
When(/^I add a product to my collection$/) do
  select(Product.first.name, from: "unassociated_product_ids[]")
  click_link(">") #<-- uses ajax
  sleep 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to explicitly wait for AJAX or Javascript to finish - instead, you should try to wait for your page to change.

Imagine that JS/AJAX that runs by clicking your link causes the product's name to now be listed in a UL/LI element on the page. So initially there is no LI with the text of the product name, but afterwards there will be. Your step should wait for that:

```
...
click_link(">")
page.should have_css("li", :text => Product.first.name)
...
```

That will wait until there is an LI element on your page with the product's name. How long will it wait? Well Capybara has a default wait time, `Capybara.default_max_wait_time`. You can set a default in `env.rb` like `Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5` or something. And then of course you can change it temporarily in a step if you know you need more time.

```
default_max_wait_time = Capybara.default_max_wait_time
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10 # Really long request
# Do stuff
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = default_max_wait_time
```

Or use `Capybara.using_wait_time` to simplify that.

```
Capybara.using_wait_time(10) do
  # Do stuff
end
```

Sometimes though you might actually have to wait for AJAX and it might be too hard or impossible for you to wait for the page to be different, and this might be outside of your control. In that case, you can make a custom method to wait for AJAX and call it from any step that needs it.

```
def wait_for_ajax
  # See: https://gist.github.com/10c41024510ee9f235e0
  # Linked from: http://techblog.fundinggates.com/blog/2012/08/capybara-2-0-upgrade-guide/
  start = Time.now
  while true
    break if (page.evaluate_script("$.active") == 0)
    if Time.now > start + Capybara.default_max_wait_time.seconds
      fail "AJAX did not register as complete after #{Capybara.default_max_wait_time} seconds!"
    end
    sleep 0.1
  end
end
```